# Problam With Writing DB to DataGridView To Specific Columns

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

im having a problam to write my DB to my DataGridView .

i have 3 tables (my data bases) and im doing join on all of them by selected values as in my code below :

```
public void ByPeople(string idToSearch)
    {
        string constring = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\sam\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\roject\roject\DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

        using (SqlConnection myconnection = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {

            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT p.Id, p.FirstName, p.LastName , m.TagNumber, m.Date, m.Group, m.Location, r.Eye, r.Shallow, r.Deep FROM PeopleTable p JOIN MainTable m ON p.Id=m.Id JOIN ResultsTable r ON r.TagNumber=m.TagNumber AND r.Date= m.Date where m.Id=@Id", myconnection))
            {
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id",idToSearch);

                myconnection.Open();

                SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
                System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                adap.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            }

        }

    }
```

and im getting an Error :

"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Group' "

and im not using any Group by or something like that , maybe its because i have a column named Group ?(m.Group in the selected values in my query) , if i deletes m.Group its working good .

and my second question  - in my dataGridView i have already writen columns names of my own , and i want to insert the data from DB to specific columns in my dataGridView , how can i do it ? beacause if im doing it like in my code , it inserts the data with the names of the columns in the DB  , and i dont want it like this , i want to insert the data to specific columns that i choose in the datagridview with the names that already there .

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Group` is a reserved keyword in SQL. You need to put brackets around all reserved keywords.

Regarding your second question: You can alias the names of the columns by using the `AS` keyword

```
SELECT p.Id, p.FirstName AS MyColumnName, p.LastName , m.TagNumber, m.[Date]
       , m.[Group], m.[Location], r.Eye, r.Shallow
       , r.Deep 
FROM PeopleTable p 
JOIN MainTable m 
  ON p.Id=m.Id 
JOIN ResultsTable r 
  ON r.TagNumber=m.TagNumber 
  AND r.Date= m.Date 
WHERE m.Id=@Id
```